# I can't find this: How do I use 4 SPACES instead of a TAB in EMACS?

Tags: php, emacs, elisp

I am making the jump to EMACS, and I can't find what I need to do in my `.emacs` file to get php-mode *AND all other modes* to insert 4 spaces instead of a TAB. Help?

UPDATE:

When I hit tab I still get 8 spaces in a plain file with the given answers. In php-mode I still get 2 spaces. Hitting tab in php mode does nothing, tab in regular EMACS adds 8 spaces.

UPDATE2:

This is what I have in my `.emacs`:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-calm-forest)

(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
```

Still in regular files 8 spaces, and in PHP files the tabbing doesn't work, or jumps around randomly now. My php-mode is from the Ubuntu 9.10 `apt-get install php-mode`

---

UDATE3:

OK Here is what I want...

1. When I hit the TAB Key, and when I always hit the TAB key, I want 4 SPACES inserted.
2. I want the TAB key to jump to the relative position of the previous line (auto tab up to the last line, again entering in SPACES)

These rules need to apply to *all files* but if necessary need to first and foremost apply to (text) and PHP files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change the variable indent-tabs-mode to nil. You can do it interactively (for just one buffer)  by `M-x set-variable`. To make it permanent (and for all buffers), put

```
 (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

in your init file.

To make a tab do just 4 spaces in most modes, also add

```
 (setq-default tab-width 4)
```

For C based modes (like PHP) you will have to do:

```
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
```

Comment: OK, that didn't help in php mode (still 2) and for general editing it used 8 spaces.

Comment: Added a line on how to change to 4 spaces in general editing. Php mode probably has its own setting for this.

Comment: You have a syntax error. I would assume it is `(setq-default tab-width 4)` And that did not help at all. And yes I am making sure EMACS is taking the new configuration each time I try it.

Comment: For modes based off the C mode, you can use the `c-basic-offset` variable to determine how many columns to indent.  Try `(setq-default c-basic-offset 4)`

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that PHP is based on C mode -- should have guessed. I will add it to my answer. Thanks jamessan.

Comment: I strongly advise you *against* changing `tab-width`.  This variable only affects the way TAB chars in the buffer are displayed.  Whereas Urda's question is about what to do when hitting the TAB key (and it seems he does not want TAB chars to be inserted).

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a (setq c-basic-indent 4). So you should have:

```
;; 4 spaces rather than tabs
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq c-basic-offset 4)
(setq c-basic-indent 4)
```

Comment: I repeat: do *not* change `tab-width` unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of TAB in Emacs (in programming modes) is to automatically indent to *the right place*, where this place is decided based on indentation rules described by the major mode (it's one of the most important job of a major-mode, actually, much more demanding in general than color-highlighting).  Of course if the line is already indented to the right place, hitting TAB won't do anything.

So you can force TAB to behave in a dumb way, like you're asking, but then you'd miss out on most of the fun.
E.g. you could do something like

```
(global-set-key "\t"
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (let ((prevline-indent (save-excursion (forward-line -1) (current-indentation))))
      (if (< (current-column) prevline-indent))
          (indent-to prevline-indent)
        (insert "    ")))))
```

But instead, I recommend you use TAB the way Emacs intended and explain to Emacs how you like your code to be indented.  Probably by setting something like:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil) ;; Prefer SPC over TAB when indenting.
(setq c-basic-offset 4)             ;; I like indenting by 4 spaces.
```

From what you say, the TAB indentation in your php-mode doesn't work right, so there might simply be a bug in your php-mode.  Tell us exactly in which case it is not working right, showing the text that gets mis-indented, and explaining in which way the indentation does not match your expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `M-x untabify` to convert all tabs to spaces.

Well in that case you can set the value of `indent-tabs-mode` to `nil` for your php minor mode.

You may also find the wiki: http://www.fnal.gov/docs/products/emacs/emacs/emacs_23.html#SEC185 and Jamie Zawinski's post: http://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html to be informative.

Comment: OK, good to know. But I want this to be a permanent setting for when I edit files in PHP and other modes.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've done.

```
;;;; Tab settings ;;;;
;Tab width is 3
(setq tab-width 3)
(setq-default tab-width 3) ;;going to force it. yessir.
;Use spaces always.
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
;Jump by 3.
(setq c-basic-offset 3)
;this defaulted to 4 and had to be reset to 3. the prior settings did not override it. Lame.
(setq perl-indent-level 3)
;Tab stop list out to col 60
;Manually set by x3
(setq tab-stop-list '(3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30 33 36 39 42 45 48 51 54 57 60))
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 `(setq-default tab-width 3)` in a row?