# How do I instruct emacs to use 4 spaces instead of the tab character for all indentation?

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation

What do I put in my `.emacs` file to use four spaces instead of the tab character for all indentation?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388367/i-cant-find-this-how-do-i-use-4-spaces-instead-of-a-tab-in-emacs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the variable [`indent-tabs-mode`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/Indent-Tabs-Mode.html). Put:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

in your .emacs to use spaces.

Comment: Thanks! That gives me eight spaces instead of a tab, but how do I switch to four spaces?

Comment: Found the answer: (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)