# Emacs PHP Indentation

Tags: php, emacs, coding-style, indentation, code-formatting

I am using Emacs with php-mode.el: http://php-mode.sourceforge.net/php-mode.el.html

I have the following lines in my .emacs file:

```
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/php-mode.el")
(require 'php-mode)
(setq c-default-style "linux" c-basic-offset 4)
```

It is working really nicely for the most part. The issue is that for certain bits of code Emacs displays the code differently to other editors. For example, I have the following code in Emacs:

```
public function showStuff($items, $Stuff) {
    $restrict = true;
    $stuff  = false;
    $moreStuff = true;

    if (($restrict && $stuff >= $moreStuff) 
        || ( $moreStuff > 10)) {
        return true;
    }           
    return false;
}
```

But viewing the same file in Eclipse/Sublime Text/Text Wrangler looks like:

```
public function showStuff($items, $Stuff) {
    $restrict = true;
    $stuff  = false;
    $moreStuff = true;

    if (($restrict && $stuff >= $moreStuff) 
    || ( $moreStuff > 10)) {
    return true;
    }           
    return false;
}
```

Can anyone comment on why I am seeing these results and a possible solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Always provide links when you are asking about third-party libraries. There is more than one php-mode.el.

Comment: My best guess would be that your file uses tabs (`\t`) for indentation of the if-block, which Emacs indents like 8 spaces and other Editors indent like 4 spaces. Could you verify that?

Comment: `M-x whitespace-mode RET` will show you whether you are mixing tabs and spaces for your indentation.

Comment: @phils and Thomas I have amended my question with the library that I am using. I think the issue probably is with tabs/spaces. I tried `M-x whitespace-mode RET` and it shows that I am using a combination of spaces and tabs but I am not sure what this means or how I can correct the problem. Do you have any more advice?

Comment: You'll find lots of information by searching here, or looking on the Emacs Wiki. The exact solution will depend upon whether you wish to be using only tabs or only spaces. `tabify` and `untabify` are also useful for sorting out the existing code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it seems you want to use spaces rather than tabs, I think this is basically a duplicate of:

[I can't find this: How do I use 4 SPACES instead of a TAB in EMACS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388367/i-cant-find-this-how-do-i-use-4-spaces-instead-of-a-tab-in-emacs)

Or if you wanted this only for PHP files, then you would use:

```el
(add-hook 'php-mode-hook 'my-php-mode-hook)
(defun my-php-mode-hook ()
  "My PHP mode configuration."
  (setq indent-tabs-mode nil
        tab-width 4
        c-basic-offset 4))
```

Before that, with the code *looking* correct in Emacs, convert the tabs to spaces with:

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `untabify` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I would also take a look at:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryIndentation

(or take note of it, at least -- indentation can be trickier than expected in Emacs, and there's lots of good information there.)

Comment: thanks for a great answer, I added that to my .emacs file and it works great. I also tested out the `untabify` command and that worked great also.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is simply that your Eclipse/Foo/Bar editors do not display the TABs in your files in the standard way (TABs have generally been defined as spanning 8 columns).  Using a mix of spaces and TABs is not a problem (similar prolems would show up if you only used TABs for indentation), there does not seem to be anything that really needs fixing in your file.  The best way to solve this is probably:

1. Report the problem with those editors (it is likely a minor configuration problem).
2. Add (setq indent-tabs-mode nil) in your .emacs so that Emacs will prefer using spaces everywhere which should circumvent these problems (tho it won't prevent you from inserting your own TABs and it won't magically change the TABs that are already there).

Comment: I think the *problem* is a potentially-ambiguous level of indentation, and that doesn't happen when only tabs (or only spaces) are used, so using tabs exclusively for indentation doesn't cause "similar problems".

Comment: @phils and Stefan thanks you for your responses. I find it hard to believe the problem is with the other editors as Emacs is the only editor which is displaying the indentation differently. I will try `(setq indent-tabs-mode nil)`, `tabify` and `untabify`. phils, what do you mean by 'potentially-ambiguous level of indentation'?

Comment: Tom: I simply meant the symptom that you're observing -- the semantic level of indentation for a given line of code varying depending upon the editor used to view it. If tabs are used exclusively then the width of each indent could still vary between editors, but the structure of the code would always remain clear.

Comment: I also have to disagree with the suggestion that other editors are at fault if they do not enforce 8-character tabs. I certainly agree that it's a good default value, but just as Emacs does not enforce this (thankfully), nor should other editors do so. A particular project might mandate a certain tab width, but unless that's the case, mixing tabs and spaces should definitely be considered a problem that needs fixing.

Comment: @phils: As already explained, the same problem would show up if he used only TABs for indentation, so the issue is not mixing spaces and TABs but varying interpretations of what TAB means.  Even if all the editors you tried other than Emacs happened to agree on TAB=4 (apparently), this setting is non-standard.  The value of 8 is the only standard one, so any system/editor/user using a value different from 8 should expect surprises when using files in a different context.

Comment: Stefan: Ah, I just figured out what you mean about the tabs-only approach being a problem. It's a valid point, but also something which can be circumvented. I differentiate between "indentation" (tabs or spaces, but not both) as an indication of the code structure, and "alignment" (which must be spaces) within a level of indentation. The [Smart Tabs](http://www.emacswiki.org/SmartTabs) approach, in other words. Sorry; I'm so used to thinking this way that I didn't cotton on to what you meant.

Comment: @phils: smart-tabs eliminate some of the problems which can show up when TABs get interpreted as different amounts of spaces, but they don't eliminate the problem that the same file will be displayed differently.